# check multiple files existing in a directory or not

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to UNIX, please help.

I have a file which has many lines, each line is a filename.

Now I want to check if each file exists in another directory with some prefixes.

For example, my text file content is

```
abc.def.ghi.jkl
mno.pqr.stu.vwx
```

I want to test if each file exists in a directory, like

```
cd <search directory>
ls -ltr *abc.def.ghi.jkl*
```

If above result is false then throw an error.

Note: The file content is DYNAMIC and I am generating this file through another script.

Comment: What shell are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: to improve your formatting in the future, highlight the text you want to appear as code, then use the `{}` formatting tools near the top right of the text input box. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected Answer

```
`ls -l > temp.cat
for i in $(cat temp.txt)
do
        ls -l *$i*
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
        then
        echo " File found"
        else
         echo " File not found for $i"
        fi
done
rm -f temp.txt`
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is

```
$ cat myList
abc.def.ghi.jkl
mno.pqr.stu.vwx
```

A quick solution is

```
  cat myList | xargs ls -ltr
```

If files are not found, the output of `ls` will complain to stdout with

```
ls: xxx: No such file or directory
```

IHTH

Comment: Thanks for your response and advice shelter...
the directory in which i m going to search will not have the exact file name .. some other things will be prefixed

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, can you restate it, with sample input, expected outputs and code your have tried? Else, please accept that answers that help you by selecting the check mark by the counter at the top left of the answer. Good luck.

Comment: also your answer is not given me a an error if the file is not existing

Comment: you'll need to illustrate your question more fully. Descriptions such as "the directory in which i m going to search will not have the exact file name" are difficult to interpret. Please give 2-3 examples of what you mean by "not the exact filename". What are the "other things that will be prefixed"? If you can't define your problem explicitly, we can't give you an explicit solution. Good luck.

Comment: when I include 'xxx' in my sample `myList`, I get the exact error message listed above (its the first line of output). Good luc.